# Kong consumer unable to find secrets

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, kong

I am testing kong for rate-limiting by api key in kubernetes 1.24. I am getting the error where the consumer is not able to find credentials.

```
time="2023-08-15T06:57:08Z" level=error msg="resource processing failed: credential \"test-apikey\" failure: failed to fetch secret: Secret kong/test-apikey not found" GVK="configuration.konghq.com/v1, Kind=KongConsumer" name=my-consumer namespace=kong
```

I have made sure that the secrets are there:

```
k get secret test-apikey -n kong
NAME          TYPE     DATA   AGE
test-apikey   Opaque   2      21h
```

Also the role has enough permissions:

```
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
 resources:
 - configmaps
 - pods
 - secrets
 - namespaces
 verbs:
 - get
 - list
```

Here is manifest for kongConsumer:

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongConsumer
metadata:
 name: my-consumer
 namespace: kong
annotations:
 kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
username: test-username
credentials:
- "test-apikey"
```

Comment: Same issue for me, when configuring the basic-auth plugin. I've tried around and older images are working. Working: kong:3.2; Not working: kong:3.3
For now I've not found a solution.

Comment: Facing the same issue also after downgrading kong to v3.2

Comment: What solved the issue for me was by updating KIC crds

Comment: update of KIC crds works for me as well

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually update other Kong Kubernetes resources as well, if you updated Kong in the meanwhile.
Copy all `CustomResourceDefintion`, `ServiceAccount`, `Role`, `ClusterRole`, `RoleBinding` and `ClusterRoleBinding` resources from the [Kong all-in-one deployment v2.11.1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/v2.11.1/deploy/single/all-in-one-dbless.yaml) or your specific version or even just [latest](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/deploy/single/all-in-one-dbless.yaml), to a new yaml file and apply it to your k8s cluster. The consumer will recover itself after the update was successful.